# Exit code 655- Bad password error

Tags: autosys

I've managed to figure out that the job I sent to the AutoSys Server is failing and the Exit Code is -655. Can anyone please tell me what that means?

Answer (score 1):

In our case, we got -655 when the disk space was full and it was not able to create new log files.

Answer (score 0):

Recheck the Owner attribute.  My experience is that the Owner is not entered correctly or it is not an authorized account for use on the Agent machine.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many reasons for -655 error code but for all the main cause is that your job is not able to find some. If you are running a script check for the permissions on the script.